# What does "of" mean in this sentence? - "Which brothel did you say she worked out of?"

Tags: prepositions

A: Which brothel did you say she worked out of?

B: I didn't. She works down there, at the back of a hat shop.

From TV show Desperate Romantics

Answer (score 1):

The expression is **to work out of** a shop/cafe/room or whatever.

It implies that the location is not very salutary. You wouldn't say that the president of a company works out of a large office.

The sentence suggests that the woman concerned is a prostitute. You could say that she **works in** a brothel. To say that she **works out of** implies that she uses it as a base.

The **of** is merely at the end of the sentence. You could rephrase it as: **Out of which brothel did you say she worked?**